# Django-Rest-Framework: Can I create a viewset with two different methods with the same url_path, but different request methods?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here's the viewset

```
class MobileDeviceViewset(ModelViewSet):
    @action(
        methods=['post', 'put', 'patch'],
        url_path='token',
        detail=True,
    )
    def update_token(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        ...

    @action(
        methods=['get'],
        url_path='token',
        detail=True,
    )
    def get_token(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        ...
```

So what I want to do here is have an endpoint `/token/` that the app will send a GET request to to check if there is a token, and get it if there is. I also want to use that same `/token/` endpoint to send an updated token to. What happens currently is that I get an error telling me that the POST/PATCH/PUT methods are not allowed on that endpoint, so it appears to only be recognizing the `get_token` method. The token object here is actually a ManyToMany through model called `MobileDeviceUser`, so I'm not just trying to update a field on the `MobileDevice` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `url_path` and `detail` are the same in both cases, why do you want two separate methods in your views??
Anyway I would recommend this way,

```
class MobileDeviceViewset(ModelViewSet):
    # your code

    @action(methods=['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch'], url_path='token', detail=True, )
    def my_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return self.get_token(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.update_token(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def update_token(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response("update token response--{}".format(request.method))

    def get_token(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response("update token response--{}".format(request.method))
```

Then you have to make some changes in your URL config,

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('mysample', MobileDeviceViewset, base_name='mobile-device')
actions = {
    "get": "my_action",
    "post": "my_action",
    "put": "my_action",
    "patch": "my_action"
}
urlpatterns = [
                  path('mysample/<pk>/token/', MobileDeviceViewset.as_view(actions=actions))

              ] + router.urls
```

Hence, your URL will some something like, **`..../mysample/3/token/`**

**NOTE**
This solution tested under `Python 3.6`, `Django==2.1` and `DRF==3.8.2`

---

## UPDATE

### Why ***`Method Not Allowed`*** error?

When a request comes to Django, it searches for the patterns in the URL configs and sends the request to the corresponding view if a match occurs.
In your case, you've defined two views (yes..it's actions though) with the same URL (as below,).

```
actions = {
    "post": "update_token",
    "put": "update_token",
    "patch": "update_token"
}

urlpatterns = [
                  path('mysample/<pk>/token/', MobileDeviceViewset.as_view(actions={"get": "get_token"})),
                  path('mysample/<pk>/token/', MobileDeviceViewset.as_view(actions=actions))

              ] + router.urls
```

In this case, a request comes (let it be a **HTTP POST**) and the URL dispatcher redirects to the **first view** which satisfies the URL path. So, the POST request goes into the **`get_token`** method, but, it's only allowed for **GET** method

---

### What is the possible solution?

**Method-1:**
As I described in the top, use a common action and distingush the **HTTP METHODS** and call appropriate methods
**Method-2:**
Use different URL path for both actions, as

```
actions = {
    "post": "my_action",
    "put": "my_action",
    "patch": "my_action"
}
urlpatterns = [
                  path('mysample/<pk>/get-token/', MobileDeviceViewset.as_view(actions={"get": "get_token"})),
                  path('mysample/<pk>/update-token/', MobileDeviceViewset.as_view(actions=actions))

              ] + router.urls
```

Comment: Thanks, while this achieves the same behavior, it's not what I was looking for. I essentially want it to redirect to a nested viewset, but using `drf-nested-routers` isn't doing what I want. I can achieve the same behavior I want by hacking some stuff together, but I was hoping for a built-in manner that I was missing.

Comment: So I want `/device/<device_id>/` to give me the device with that ID, and then I want `/device/<device_id>/token/` to behave like `ModelViewSet`. I think it may actually be possible somehow with DRF's `HyperlinkedSerializerField`, but I'll have to play with it later. For now I've just gone with a simpler route of having `/get-token/` and `/update-token/`

Comment: You'd said you need **same url path**...and now you are saying two paths, which are `/get-token/` ,`/update-token/`

Comment: I never said I *need* the same URL path. I just would have preferred it. My point is that if I can't implement it in the desired method on the back-end, then I'll just go with two endpoints. The front-end developers don't care.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this via:

```
class MobileDeviceViewset(ModelViewSet):    

    @action(
        methods=['get'],
        url_path='token',
        url_name='token',
        detail=True,
    )
    def get_token(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        ...

    @get_token.mapping.post
    @get_token.mapping.put
    @get_token.mapping.patch
    def update_token(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        ...
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#routing-additional-http-methods-for-extra-actions